# Size of file names on tabs in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In notepad++, the names of the files I have open that appear on each tab are in a tiny font that's unreadable (using a large screen at low resolution).  Is there a way to change the size of the font that's used on those tabs?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can try "Reduce" option under Settings > Preferences > General > Tab Bar.

Comment: ... and don't forget to uncheck "darken inactive tabs". However, I find that on big screens, the "Document List Panel" (can be found on the same settings page) is just the far more convenient way to switch tabs. (The "Switch to next/previous document" shortcuts are also a good alternative.)

Answer (score 3):

First; in Preferences => General untick the reduce check box as well as the darken tab checkbox.
This will have an immediate impact.

Next, in Preferences => Style Configurator => General Styles => Inactive tabs;
Click on the foreground color and change it to black.

I have attempted to change the font size in the tabs by doing the following, but it does not appear to have an affect.

Open the stylers.xml file in your Notepad++ folder and I have not found this to work with 64bit Notepad++.

do a search in stylers.xml for tab, not tabs. You will find four lines beginning with WidgetStyle

```
    <WidgetStyle name="Active tab focused indicator" styleID="0" fgColor="FAAA3C" />
    <WidgetStyle name="Active tab unfocused indicator" styleID="0" fgColor="FFCAB0" />
    <WidgetStyle name="Active tab text" styleID="0" fgColor="000000" />
    <WidgetStyle name="Inactive tabs" styleID="0" fgColor="000000" bgColor="C0C0C0" />

    <WidgetStyle name="Active tab focused indicator" styleID="0" fgColor="FAAA3C" fontSize="14" />
    <WidgetStyle name="Active tab unfocused indicator" styleID="0" fgColor="FFCAB0" fontSize="14" />
    <WidgetStyle name="Active tab text" styleID="0" fgColor="000000" fontSize="14" />
    <WidgetStyle name="Inactive tabs" styleID="0" fgColor="000000" bgColor="C0C0C0" fontSize="14" />
```

It would be good for users in general if programs were designed so that the user can change the font size of the GUI. Microsoft's nonsensical increase font size panel doesn't actually help users as that increase also increases the size of everything on the desktop and most people will be served quite nicely with only a larger font size.

Who knows, maybe the developers of Notepad++ will see this and make sure the font size in the tabs will change based on the stylers.xml settings.

Answer (score -1):

try to go to Control Panel > Fonts > Font Settings > Restore default font settings. 
Apply. Restart computer.

Works for me